# Is there any way to use sass instead of node-sass (default for sass-loader) in Nuxt.js?

Tags: sass, nuxt.js, node-sass, sass-loader

I'm trying to use sass package instead of node-sass in Nuxt.js. I found a config like this;

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        implementation: require('sass'), // This line must in sass option
      },
    },
  }
}
```

but I couldn't figure out where to put this code in Nuxt.js.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its already pointed on [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#loaders-sass-and-loaders-scss).

`nuxt.config.js`:

```
build: {

  ...

  loaders: {
    sass: {
      implementation: require('sass')
    },
    scss: {
      implementation: require('sass')
    }
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: You saved my day! I have a monorepo where node-sass and sass are installed and webpack seems to use node-sass as a default.