# In Vue CLI how do I use sass instead of node-sass (default for sass-loader)?

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, sass, vue-cli

I came across this answer but I'm not using Nuxt.js. I'm using the Vue CLI.

[Is there any way to use sass instead of node-sass (default for sass-loader) in Nuxt.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57249076/is-there-any-way-to-use-sass-instead-of-node-sass-default-for-sass-loader-in-n)

In the official docs for Vue CLI it shows an example using Dart Sass (sass) but in the Vue Loader docs it shows an example using Node Sass (node-sass). I'd like to use just sass but am receiving errors for the missing node module node-sass. Where I can I make the config changes to use Dart Sass instead?

Comment: I could be wrong but from memory, it's just a matter of removing the `node-sass` dependency from `package.json` and adding `sass`. You'll want to run `npm prune` too to remove the `node-sass` files from `node_modules`

Comment: @Phil I will give that a go, thank you! I originally ran 'npm i sass-loader sass' and it gave me the error off the bat but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Phil Got it, thank you!

Comment: What error was it? I think the main problem would be that both Sass implementations provide a `sass` binary so trying to run something like `npx sass` would be ambiguous

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easiest to select it from the CSS Pre-processors options when creating a new Vue CLI project with `vue create`.

- Manually select features
- CSS Pre-processors (*)

*Screenshot:*
[image]

---

Example `package.json`:

```js
"devDependencies": {
  "sass-loader": "^7.2.0",
  "sass": "^1.22.10"
}
```

`sass` = dart-sass

`node-sass` = node-sass

Comment: and whats the solution if you already have a project where you need to change the settings?

Comment: @Deniz `npm install -D sass-loader sass`